# How should I balance risk when choosing between two PhD offers?

Tags: phd, physics

I recently completed a Masters in theoretical physics. I was fortunate enough to receive two fully funded PhD offers in Europe with very good groups in their respective fields, and am having difficulties choosing between them. They both pay the same, are in comparable cities with similar commute times, have enthusiastic advisors, etc.

The first would take 4-5 years, is in an experimental condensed matter physics group but with very very strong connections to a theoretical physics group at the same institute, with opportunities for co-mentorship with them. The funding for research is virtually unlimited. I spoke to some people in the know, who told me "the group is very prestigious and strong in technique, you will publish amazing papers, and the group's PhD and postdoc record is unbelievable." However, the group leader is very focused on certain topics and does not allow too much freedom outside of them. I am indeed quite interested in the theoretical aspects of the research there, but am afraid that if my interests drift too much outside of there, I might end up unhappy, since my current interests already lean on the less applicable side.

The second offer would take 3-4 years, is in a relatively applicable field of high-energy theory (but not particle physics, which I would not be interested in doing) that has a larger community in Europe than in the US. I wrote my thesis on a topic closely related to this, and I could jump right into some very exciting work. However, it is a small community and career prospects would likely be worse than in the previous case.

The bottom line is that I can choose to either 1) be risky with interests now, guarantee academic career 2) guarantee interests now, risk academic career. The difficulty lies in that judging the risk levels involved with either is very difficult. Are there any crucial factors that I may have missed that I should take into account? Does anyone have a personal experience similar to mine? Did you end up happy with your choice?

Comment: This is a decision only you can make...

Comment: Indeed. I am really only asking for insights that would come more naturally from people in these fields and for which I do not have the knowledge or experience to know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with your field, but in general, I think the biggest risk here is calculating with any guarantees.

Say you pick option A. Even if you work on something you are not happy with for 6 years, there is NO guarantee whatsoever that there is an academic career at the end of the line. So, it is up to you whether you want to work on topics that you don't prefer (are you sure that you might not learn/grow to care about them if your advisor really is so amazing and the surroundings are inspiring? can you still switch fields after or will you be working this for the rest of your life?) to best prepare you for an academic career (assuming this is true with said advisor and group).

Say you pick option B - can you guarantee that your interests are met? How important is field size in Europe and US (unclear to me, but you mention something about it so maybe important to you?) If it is a smaller community, that might also mean less competition? Or a faster way to build a network with key people?

Go about this the scientific way: list all possible parameters and pros and cons you can come up with, do the math (i.e. score all of them). Ask advise from mentors/friends etc. And then follow your now well informed gut.